# Apache nifi in docker: Unable to access nifi UI

Tags: docker, apache-nifi

I create a docker image for apache nifi 1.22.0, exposing ports in dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 8080 8443 10000 8000
```

Then I launch a docker container:

```
docker run -it --cpus=4 --user root --memory=10g --publish 8080:8080 \
--hostname nifi-0 --network my-net \
....some volumes...
apache-nifi:1.22.0
```

Container is launched sucessfully, But I am not able to access UI. I tried all possible URLS, but nothing works:

```
localhost:8080/nifi
nifi-0:8080/nifi
localhost:8000/nifi
nifi-0:8000/nifi
```

Looking into the console logs, I observed this:

```
NIFI_WEB_PROXY_HOST was not set but NiFi is configured to run in a secure mode. The NiFi UI may be inaccessible if using port mapping or connecting through a proxy.
```

Is this the reason I am not able to access nifi UI? If yes, how can I set NIFI_WEB_PROXY_HOST?

Edit:

I added this to my docker run command, and now I am able to access UI on localhost:8080/nifi.

```
-e NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT='8080'
```

Though when I check nifi.properties inside docker, I see this:

```
....
nifi.web.http.host=nifi-0
nifi.web.http.port=8080
nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=

#############################################

nifi.web.https.host=
nifi.web.https.port=
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.https.application.protocols=http/1.1
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
nifi.web.max.header.size=16 KB
nifi.web.proxy.context.path=
nifi.web.proxy.host=
.....
```

nifi.web.http.host is nifi-0, nifi.web.http.port is 8080 now. Earlier both these were empty. Also, nifi.web.proxy.host is still empty.

Somehow all this combines well to make it work for me.

'nifi-0:8080/nifi' doesn't work though.

Comment: You should be able to see a log message which states the address the UI is accessible from, do check if you are using the same

Comment: after starting container it does again assign port to these setting in nifi.properties: nifi.web.https.host=
nifi.web.https.port=

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to access the service running on your localhost, simply set the `nifi.web.http.host` property to `0.0.0.0` or `localhost` instead of `nifi-0`.

restart your docker and test `curl http://localhost:8080/nifi`

Here's an example of a docker-compose.yml to run NiFi in secure mode:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
   
   nifi:
     image:  apache/nifi:1.22.0
     hostname: nifi
     container_name: nifi
     restart: on-failure 
     environment: 
       - NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_PORT=9443
       - SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_USERNAME=admin 
       - SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_PASSWORD=ctsBtRBKHRAx69EqUghvvgEvjnaLjFEB 
       - NIFI_HOME=/opt/nifi/nifi-current
       - NIFI_LOG_DIR=/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs
       - NIFI_TOOLKIT_HOME=/opt/nifi/nifi-toolkit-current
       - NIFI_PID_DIR=/opt/nifi/nifi-current/run
       - NIFI_BASE_DIR=/opt/nifi
     ports:
       - '9443:9443'
     healthcheck:
       test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "https://localhost:9443/health"]
       interval: '30s'
       timeout: '20s'
       retries: 3  
       start_period: '5s'
     volumes:
       - data:/var/data
       - nifi:/opt/nifi
      

volumes:
  data:
  nifi:
```